# FramerJS: Add attribute + value to layer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, framerjs

I've tried using the following code in FramerJS to create a new attribute + value, but it produces nothing:

```
$('div[name]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('groupName', $(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: I have no idea what FramerJS is . but have you tried using **data-attribute** ? I am not sure if you can create that attribute *groupName* but I'm almost certain that you can create a **data-attribute** e.g., "data-groupname"

Comment: It needs to be an attribute named groupName.